# How to show image which got from spring boot by jquery onto DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, spring-boot, download

I have to load image from server spring boot and show this image onto my DOM by Jquery AJAX.
I try creating a controller and return data in byte format and do as bellow. But, btw, nothing is shown.
[this is my JQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Ud4.png)

[And this is my controller from spring boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOn8W.png)

Comment: add code directly instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the URL of the image to img tag like below and it will load the image automatically.

```
<img src="${serverContextPath}/getTopBanner" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, however This is not effecting